# only one gcm notification open when android app is close

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

iam developing an android app in which iam getting more than one gcm notification all notifications open with different data when app is open but when app is close i get more than one notification but only one open and when i click on other notification it doesn't restart activity with different data.

```
    String title = intent.getExtras().getString("title"); 
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("info"); 
    String lat = intent.getExtras().getString("lat"); 
    String lng = intent.getExtras().getString("lng"); 
    Intent notificationIntent = null;
    if(title.equals("blockage"))
    {
         notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ViewBlockage.class);

    }
    else if(title.equals("icrequest"))
    {   
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, IntercarAlert.class);
        message=intent.getExtras().getString("reqMessage"); // change the message here for request message
        notificationIntent.putExtra("reqName", intent.getExtras().getString("userName"));
    }
    else if(title.equals("icresponse"))
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, InterCarResponseAlert.class);
    }
    notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("lat", lat);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("lng", lng);
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, gcmCounter, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // update current must for every time get updated pending intent otherwise it will provide wrong intent values
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appName, message, pIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(gcmCounter, notification); 
    gcmCounter++;
```

Comment: Can you post your activity code?

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationManager.notify(gcmCounter, notification);
```

Here change value of gcmCounter each time. You can see multiple notifications at a time in the notification area.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) says:

**If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.**

Comment: how can i solve this problem because when app is open i can see all notifications with different set of data but when close i get all notifications but only open one.

Comment: ok now my all notifications open but first i have to close already open notification then to open other if i already open a notification and i open another nothing happens

Comment: With the id given(gcmCounter in your case) cancel the notification that you want, and rest will be still there.

Comment: can u please give me code how to cancel notification and how to get already open notification id

Comment: While you create a notification, save its id somewhere in your app. and to cancel a notification, notificationManager.cancel(id);

Comment: notificationManager.cancelAll() will cancel all your notifications.

Comment: What you could do is to set id as extraInt in notificationIntent. And when you go to activity, get extra and cancel it.

Comment: actually the problem is suppose i have a two notification if i open one notification now activity show me data while activity is running i click on another notification nothing happens i want if activity of one notification is already running i click on another notification it will open another activity that kind of behavior iam achieving when app is open but when app is close i have to first close already running activity then click on other notification to open activity again with different data.

Comment: So do you want to know if your app is running or not? Or were you able to do that already?

Answer (score 0):

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK clears previous Intent and new task assigned when you click on notification whether first notification is already opened.